# Get Thumb image and title of particular Website URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api, skype

[image]

I have to display thumb image and get title of WEB URL same as LinkedIN app and Skype app in iOS?

Is there any Solution?

Comment: This question is too broad and lacks and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The problem statement is also unclear.  What is the "thumb image" you want?

Comment: See this demo : https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/PreViewInIOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView) written in Swift, but you can use in Objective-C.

[This](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView/blob/master/URLEmbeddedViewSample/URLEmbeddedViewSample/OGObjcSampleViewController.m) is Objective-C sample code. Please check it.

```
#import <URLEmbeddedView/URLEmbeddedView-Swift.h>
#import <MisterFusion/MisterFusion-Swift.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) URLEmbeddedView *embeddedView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.textView.text = @"https://github.com/";

    [OGDataProvider sharedInstance].updateInterval = [NSNumber days:10];

    self.embeddedView = [[URLEmbeddedView alloc] initWithUrl:@""];
    [self.containerView addLayoutSubview:self.embeddedView andConstraints:@[
        self.embeddedView.Top,
        self.embeddedView.Right,
        self.embeddedView.Left,
        self.embeddedView.Bottom
    ]];
}

- (IBAction)didTapFetchButton:(id)sender {
    [self.embeddedView loadURL:self.textView.text completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: can you check this please: https://github.com/marty-suzuki/URLEmbeddedView/issues/90

Answer (score 9):

Here is the easiest way to find the favicon icon of URL

```
NSString *myURLString = @"http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com";
NSURL *myURL=[NSURL URLWithString: myURLString];
NSData *myData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

UIImage *myImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData];
```

Swift Version:

```
let myURLString = "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com"
let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)!
let myData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(myURL)
let myImage = UIImage(data: myData)!
```

May this helps lot

**UPDATE**

Below is the swift library which helps to load images like you want.

[URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView)

[Here You can check actual work of library.](https://appetize.io/embed/0b75yp0g7mxp3d9wzkvzyx64tc?device=iphone5s&scale=75&autoplay=false&orientation=portrait&deviceColor=black&xdocMsg=true)

Comment: This URL gives only fav small icon 12X12. I need big icon and it's description same as Linkedin app and Skype app.

Comment: @Parthpatel1105 I update my answer please review that.

Comment: Thanks for giving this. It is exactly same which i need. But i need for Objective C and it is for Swift.

Comment: @Parthpatel1105 same project also available into objective C..https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView

Comment: @Parthpatel1105 I edited the answer to show the swift version!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this: "An NSURL extension for showing preview info of webpages"
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/urlpreview

```
func fetchPageInfo(completion: ((title: String?, description: String?, previewImage: String?) -> Void), failure: ((errorMessage: String) -> Void)) {

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: self)
        let newUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36"
        request.setValue(newUserAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        ValidationQueue.queue.cancelAllOperations()

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: ValidationQueue.queue, completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    failure(errorMessage: "Url receive no response")
                })
                return
            }

            if let urlResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if urlResponse.statusCode >= 200 && urlResponse.statusCode < 400 {
                    if let data = data {

                        if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                            let title = doc.title
                            var description: String? = nil
                            var previewImage: String? = nil
                            print("title: \(title)")
                            if let nodes = doc.head?.xpath("//meta").enumerate() {
                                for node in nodes {
                                    if node.element["property"]?.containsString("description") == true ||
                                    node.element["name"] == "description" {
                                        print("description: \(node.element["content"])")
                                        description = node.element["content"]
                                    }

                                    if node.element["property"]?.containsString("image") == true &&
                                        node.element["content"]?.containsString("http") == true {
                                            previewImage = node.element["content"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                completion(title: title, description: description, previewImage: previewImage)
                            })
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        failure(errorMessage: "Url received \(urlResponse.statusCode) response")
                    })
                    return
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: But some URL does not return image. Like google, flipkart, youtube.

And also i need this code in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to download the html of the site, then parse it for the `<title>` tag (which gives you the title)

and the `<link rel="icon" ... >` tag which gives you the Favicon.
[Wikipedia article on Favicon link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

Note that neither the title, nor the favicon are guaranteed to exist, though most sites do provide a title, and most major ones to provide a Favicon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the home page
2. Parse for meta properties
   like og:image and og:url
3. Their content is what you need.

Comment: Actually some website give Proper URL but some does not give. So do you have proper code?

Comment: Most of them provide <link rel="shortcut icon" href="---.ico" /> so this will ensure you a safe backup if you don't find og:image.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, however it's worth noting that a favicon is either *16x16 pixels* or *32x32 pixels*. This is probably not sufficient for the size and resolution you wish to achieve.

There is no textbook way to achieve this, but one way could be to send a request to google for the **website title + " icon"** (for example "Facebook icon"), and pick the first result.

As for the title of the website, if you're looking for the title displayed in your browser when you enter the website you have to parse the html looking for the `<title> </title>` tag.

Achieving both of this could prove challenging, but it's definitely not impossible. There might be some sort of service out there that provides this, but not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this library and it works for youtube, flipkart.

https://github.com/myell0w/MTDURLPreview

```
[MTDURLPreview loadPreviewWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.flipkart.com"] completion:^(MTDURLPreview *preview, NSError *error) {

    }];

Printing description of preview->_title:
Online Shopping India | Buy Mobiles, Electronics, Appliances, Clothing and More Online at Flipkart.com
Printing description of preview->_domain:
www.flipkart.com
Printing description of preview->_imageURL:
http://img1a.flixcart.com/www/promos/new/20160701_015447_730x300_monsoon.jpg
```

Comment: would you please explain the steps to add MTDURLPreview to a project?